# Tensorflow predict the class of output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, categorical-data

I have tried the example with keras but was not with LSTM. My model is with LSTM in Tensorflow and I am willing to predict the output in the form of classes as the keras model thus with `predict_classes`.
The Tensorflow model I am trying is something like this:

```
seq_len=10
n_steps = seq_len-1 
n_inputs = x_train.shape[2]
n_neurons = 50
n_outputs = y_train.shape[1]
n_layers = 2
learning_rate = 0.0001
batch_size =100
n_epochs = 1000
train_set_size = x_train.shape[0]
test_set_size = x_test.shape[0]

tf.reset_default_graph()
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_outputs])
layers = [tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons,activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, use_peepholes = True)  for layer in range(n_layers)]

multi_layer_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(layers)
rnn_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_layer_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

stacked_rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, n_neurons]) 
stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_outputs, n_outputs)
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_steps, n_outputs])
outputs = outputs[:,n_steps-1,:]                                       
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y)) 
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) 
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

I am encoding the with sklearn LabelEncoder as:

```
encoder_train = LabelEncoder()
encoder_train.fit(y_train)
encoded_Y_train = encoder_train.transform(y_train)
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y_train)
```

The data is converted to sparse matrix kinda thing in binary format.
When I tried to predict the output I got the following:

```
actual==>  [[0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]] 
predicted==>  [[0.3112209  0.3690182  0.31357136]
 [0.31085992 0.36959863 0.31448898]
 [0.31073445 0.3703295  0.31469804]
 [0.31177694 0.37011752 0.3145326 ]
 [0.31220382 0.3692756  0.31515726]
 [0.31232828 0.36947766 0.3149037 ]
 [0.31190437 0.36756667 0.31323162]
 [0.31339088 0.36542615 0.310322  ]
 [0.31598282 0.36328828 0.30711085]]
```

What I was expecting for the label based on the encoding done. As the Keras model thus. See the following:

```
predictions = model.predict_classes(X_test, verbose=True)
print("REAL VALUES:",reverse_category(Y_test,axis=1))
print("PRED VALUES:",predictions)
print("REAL COLORS:")
print(encoder.inverse_transform(reverse_category(Y_test,axis=1)))
print("PREDICTED COLORS:")
print(encoder.inverse_transform(predictions))
```

The output is something like the following:

```
REAL VALUES: [1 1 1 ... 1 2 1]
PRED VALUES: [2 1 1 ... 1 2 2]
REAL COLORS:
['ball' 'ball' 'ball' ... 'ball' 'bat' 'ball']
PREDICTED COLORS:
['bat' 'ball' 'ball' ... 'ball' 'bat' 'bat']
```

Kindly, let me know what I can do in the tensorflow model that will get me the result with respect to the encoding done.
I am using `Tensorflow 1.12.0 and Windows 10`

Comment: Is there someone who can help me with what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Does anyone has any opinion on my issue please let me know? The tensorflow guys are you having a look at what I am trying to achieve, because I do not get any response from them here or in the discussions

Comment: Hi! Can  you please post or better link to the complete code which can be executed. Without it, it's hard to test and give you the solution. I assume the solution is simple.

Comment: @dsalaj Hello amigo, thank you for your comment here. I have creates a gist for it. You can check it here and try the code if you are willing to: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/a05086f2b881c16d52bbd34df8eb6a29 Hope this will help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are trying to map the predicted class probabilities back to class labels. Each row in the list of output predictions contains the three predicted class probabilities. Use `np.argmax` to obtain the one with the highest predicted probability in order to map to the predicted class label:

```
import numpy as np

predictions = [[0.3112209,  0.3690182,  0.31357136],
 [0.31085992, 0.36959863, 0.31448898],
 [0.31073445, 0.3703295, 0.31469804],
 [0.31177694, 0.37011752, 0.3145326 ],
 [0.31220382, 0.3692756, 0.31515726],
 [0.31232828, 0.36947766, 0.3149037 ],
 [0.31190437, 0.36756667, 0.31323162],
 [0.31339088, 0.36542615, 0.310322  ],
 [0.31598282, 0.36328828, 0.30711085]] 

np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
```

Gives:

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

In this case, class 1 is predicted 9 times.

As noted in the comments: this is exactly what Keras does under the hood, as you'll see [in the source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b80f3bd3a227d837790395378b14150dd11e02b7/keras/engine/sequential.py#L269).

Comment: That is exactly what [Keras does](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/b80f3bd3a227d837790395378b14150dd11e02b7/keras/engine/sequential.py#L269) too behind the scenes :)

Comment: Please allow me to check it on my notebook. I will get back if it is working for me. I guess it should.

Comment: I tried your solution but I got the predicted output as: `actual==>  [0 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 2]` and `predicted==>  [[ 716 3017 3050]] ` when I tried this: `print("\npredicted==> ",np.argmax(y_train_pred, axis=1)[:9],"\n")` Please let me know why the output I got is that weird.

Comment: @nuric: nice, I wasn't aware of this. I'll add it to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JafferWilson: from your code gist, I can see that you are dealing with three dimensions in your output. Try taking the `argmax` over the last dimension: `np.argmax(y_train_pred, axis=-1)`

Comment: But is the right way? Why was the issue with `axis=1` wwhere as `axis=-1` gives different replies, like all 2's or 1's or 0's. May I know something about it please.?

Comment: You just need to take the argmax over the dimension that contains the class probabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I can try with it.

Comment: @nuric I am new to AI could you help me https://stackoverflow.com/q/63441103/4723876